# When I try to install DIscord on command line, get could not build wheels error

Tags: python, pip, discord

When I type "pip install Discord" I get the error

```
DEPRECATION: Configuring installation scheme with distutils config files is deprecated and will no longer work in the near future. If you are using a Homebrew or Linuxbrew Python, please see discussion at https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/76621
Collecting discord
  Using cached discord-1.7.3-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 kB)
Collecting discord.py>=1.7.3
  Using cached discord.py-1.7.3-py3-none-any.whl (786 kB)
Collecting aiohttp<3.8.0,>=3.6.0
  Using cached aiohttp-3.7.4.post0.tar.gz (1.1 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting chardet<5.0,>=2.0
  Using cached chardet-4.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (178 kB)
Collecting async-timeout<4.0,>=3.0
  Using cached async_timeout-3.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (8.2 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.3.0 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from aiohttp<3.8.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py>=1.7.3->discord) (21.4.0)
Collecting typing-extensions>=3.6.5
  Using cached typing_extensions-4.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: multidict<7.0,>=4.5 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from aiohttp<3.8.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py>=1.7.3->discord) (6.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: yarl<2.0,>=1.0 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from aiohttp<3.8.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py>=1.7.3->discord) (1.7.2)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.0 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from yarl<2.0,>=1.0->aiohttp<3.8.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py>=1.7.3->discord) (3.3)
Building wheels for collected packages: aiohttp
  WARNING: Building wheel for aiohttp failed: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/emmasteuer/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/c4'
Failed to build aiohttp
ERROR: Could not build wheels for aiohttp, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

My python is up to date and so is pip. What does this error message mean?

Comment: You may need to install `pyproject.toml-based projects`

Comment: You need to fix permissions in your home directory: `sudo chown -R emmasteuer /Users/emmasteuer` or more generic `sudo chown -R $USER $HOME`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ubuntu or similar debian like. Try again, use "sudo" at first command. Because there is the error message "Permission Denied"

```
sudo pip install Discord
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).